# laravel 6 и monolog

Tags: laravel, логирование

Вообщем я пишу api на laravel 6.4 и мне нужно в некоторых местах записывать ошибку в лог при этом название лога файла должно быть примерно таким: `Компания+дата (ггммдд) +время` и единственный вариант как это сделать это через monolog, но я так и не нашел как правильно через него логировать данные в файл такого вида. Поэтому буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Дык, Laravel по умолчанию пишет логи через monolog... Но в Вашем случае систему логов использовать не нужно. Почему просто через стандартную функцию PHP `file_put_contents` не записывать всё? И название какое хотите задавайте, и контент.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, но тогда это будет выглядеть как костыль, а это не есть хорошо.
Но как рабочий вариант вполне можно использовать.

Comment: просто не нужно всё усложнять. Если будет куча обёрток - зачем? При том, эта же обёртка точно эту же функцию будет под катом использовать, потому что она тоже на PHP.